# PDFClown image extraction images inverted

Tags: pdf, pdfclown

I'm working with PDFClown and I'm trying to extract images from a pdf file. I use the example code provided by the source code that can be found at http://pdfclown.org.

ImageExtractionSample.java.

The problem is the images are negative and flipped horizontally. Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps the images are stored that way. Provide a link to a sample PDF and we'll have a look.

Comment: In response to your request, I opened a ticket on the project's tracker: https://sourceforge.net/p/clown/bugs/77/

Answer (score 1):

Check with other PDF files to see if other PDF files are also giving the rotated or flipped images. [ImageExtractionSample.java](https://github.com/zuki/PDFClown/blob/master/java/pdfclown.samples.cli/src/org/pdfclown/samples/cli/ImageExtractionSample.java) is not checking rotation or matrix defined transformations for the image object but just writes the content to a file as is (so it will work for JPG images but not for CCIT encoded images for example).

So there are things to consider when you extract image from PDF:

- image can be rotated using the attached transformation matrix (CTM);
- image can be rotated/transformed as part of the form which is transformed;
- image can be placed without transformation on a page but the page itself is rotated;
- image may contain the overlaid Mask on top of it (and the Mask can be rotated and transformed);
- JPG image is stored pretty much as is but there are other formats supported by PDF like CCIT compression, LZW compressed images etc;

But the general suggestion is that when you extract JPG image from PDF using PDFClown you should just flip and rotate extracted images like [suggested on the SourceForge project discussion page](http://sourceforge.net/p/clown/discussion/607162/thread/e42d7c74/#4d5c).

if you could point to the particular PDF sample file then it would be easier to suggest the solution.

If you're on Windows then you may use this free [PDF Multitool](http://bytescout.com/products/pdfmultitool/index.html) utility to compare non-transformed and transformed images from PDF using "Extract raw images (without transformation)" option in images extraction dialog.

*Disclaimer: I work for ByteScout, the PDF Multitool utility is free for both commercial and non-commercial purposes.*

Comment: This does not really answer the question, does it? The OP is *working with PDFClown* and, thus, seemingly asks for a solution for use with PDFClown. Is this mere advertising of the Multitool?

Comment: Nope. I've checked the code for ImageExtractionSample.java and it is not checking for any transformation applied to an image and just dumps the image body into the file. And was not able to find the way to get the linked transformation matrix using the API. So anyway I suggested the free (for bot non commercial and commercial purposes!) tool that can be used to instantly compare output with and without transformations applied.

Comment: *Nope...* - Hhmm, ok. BTW, the downvote was not by me but happened about at the same time as I created my comment, I saw it when I refreshed after writing the it... Seems someone else also assumed this to be spam and did not take the time to ask.

Comment: And it would be worth to mention that the page itself can be rotated as well , will update the answer to provide more clarity.

Comment: @mkl thank you for the comment, I've expanded the answer to provide more information on things to consider when doing image extraction.

Comment: Actually there are even more things to consider, e.g. transparency and blend modes. But an exhaustive discussion of this would really be too much for a stackoverflow answer.

Comment: The problem seems to be the OS I was running the example on I was using Mac OS on Windows it works just fine.

Comment: @Smek thank for letting us know! Seems like JPG files you extract contain metatags to rotate & flip which are interpreted correctly on Windows but not on Mac. I mean maybe the issue is in the image viewers not in images themselves.